# Is it too much to call invalidate on every touch under certain condition

Tags: android

When an image is being dragged using touch over another custom view, I am setting the background color of the custom view from green to red. Off course I am listening to the onTouchEvents and I am comparing the coordinates of the dragged view to the custom view to see if there is a collision. Once collision is determined, I set the color and call invalidate on the view.

So invalidate is being called on every touch (when there is a collision). Is this frown upon? I feel the device heating up when this happens so not sure if this is normal when it comes to games

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View#nvalidate()` indicates that a `View` needs to be redrawn and signals a draw pass.  You can call this 50 times in a row, and it will only signal one draw pass. The draw pass will happen as soon as the system regains control on the main thread (or perhaps a little later depending on any other background operations that take control).

If you are animating something as you are with this custom View, then you are calling many draw passes to begin with so you may not even need to call `View#invalidate()` and simply just wait for the screen to redraw.

In fact, you can [look at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and see that `invalidate()` is being called at the end of `setBackground()` to begin with. It's actually pretty rare to need to call it when you're changing properties of a `View` that the `View` itself is in control of. It's only needed if there are drawing operations that you're doing in addition to what the `View` itself is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. The thing is that the custom view OnDraw will draw colored lines and fill color depending if there is collision or not. That's why I check if there is a collision and if there, I set a flag and call invalidate.

Comment: Ok.  That's fine. That is precisely the reason you would need to call it. It's not going to be a problem calling it too much. Games and heavy math intensive apps will heat up the CPU.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the term `draw pass`. You said if we call `invalidate` 50 times in a row, it will only signal one draw pass. Does this also mean `onDraw` will be called just once?

Comment: @Jenix Yes.  That's what it means. Maybe a better term would be a `re-draw event`. Basically, the event gets put in Android's main event loop. When the loop comes back around, the redraw happens. If a view is already invalidated, then there's no need for it to add another event because the first one hasn't happened yet.